# Redirect systemd script output to console

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, systemd

How can I redirect output of script which is run by systemd ExecStart script to boot console?

I need  to debug what is wrong with script until boot but I can't use journalctl because it's embedded linux with ROM rootfs.

Now my .service file looks like:

```
[Unit]
Description=Init script
After=network.target
Before=getty@tty1.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/test_init_script
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/echo -e \033%G
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
WorkingDirectory=/
Enviroment=TERM=xterm

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

test_init_script:

```
#!/bin/sh -
echo "Test!"
```

And it didn't work, after boot I receive message:

```
#systemctl status test_init_script.service
test_init_script.service - Init script
 Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/test_init_script.service)
 Active: failed (Result: exit-code) Since Thu 1970-01-01 08:26:03 CST; 19s ago
Process: 170 ExecStartOre=/usr/bin/echo -e -G (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
```

Did anyone know how to redirect script output to terminal?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/view-stdout-stderr-of-systemd-service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I resolve this problem by building image with changed file:

```
/etc/journald.conf
```

Where I change storage option to volatile:

```
Storage=volatile
```

This option means that all journald data will be store in RAM so this is a workaround for read only file system.

Please refer to **journald** manual page to see more options.